Algorithm to find a solution that Satisfies different conditions at the same time
I need to create an algorithm to crop an image with dimensions that satisfies couple of different conditions at the same time. For example the eye level has to be 60-70% of the image's height and the head should occupy 40-50% of the image height while keeping 1:1 ratio and keeping the resolution above 1000px.
(The eye level and face dimensions are already calculated)
What kind of algorithm could achieve the solution efficiently if one existed?
I tried bruteforcing (60% eye level + 40 face height, 61% eye level + 41 face height, ....)
But as you could imagine it's very slow
I need some help

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
